# Ask the user to enter a String to indicate he has more data to enter, or if he is done

Tags: java

Everything is working properly but I need assistance with making a loop that enables a user to input values for all any and food. Also, some codes weren't able to be posted here so i took a screenshot of it. 
https://prnt.sc/r6nptj

```
    System.out.println("Are you male or female? (M/F)");
     gender = kboard.next();

     System.out.println("Enter your weight in lbs.");
     weight = kboard.nextDouble();

     System.out.println("Enter your height in inches.");
     height = kboard.nextDouble();

     System.out.println("Enter your age in years.");
     age = kboard.nextDouble();

     BMRw = 655+(4.35 * weight)+(4.7 * height)-(4.7 * age);

     BMRm = 665+(6.23 * weight)+(12.7 * height)-(6.8 * age);

     boolean isMale = gender.startsWith("M");
     if (isMale == true) {
         BMRm = 665+(6.23 * weight)+(12.7 * height)-(6.8 * age);
         System.out.println(" Your Basal Metabolism Rate is " + BMRm);

         double noExercise = (BMRm * 1.2);
    System.out.println("Your Basal Metabolism Rate when you don't engange in exercise is "  + noExercise);

    double lightExercise = (BMRm * 1.375);
    System.out.println("Your Basal Metabolism Rate when you engange in light exercises one to three days a week " + lightExercise);

    double intensely = (BMRm * 1.725);
    System.out.println(" Your Basal Metabolism Rate when you exercise intensely six to seven days a week " + intensely);

     double activeJob = (BMRm * 1.9);
     System.out.println("Your Basal Metabolism Rate when you exercise intensely six to seven days a week while having a physically active job " + activeJob); 

     }

     else {
         BMRw = 655+(4.35 * weight)+(4.7 * height)-(4.7 * age);
         System.out.println(" Your Basal Metabolism Rate is " + BMRw);

         double noExercise = (BMRw * 1.2);
            System.out.println("Your Basal Metabolism Rate when you don't engange in exercise is "  + noExercise);

            double lightExercise = (BMRw * 1.375);
            System.out.println("Your Basal Metabolism Rate when you engange in light exercises one to three days a week " + lightExercise);

            double moderateExercise = (BMRw * 1.55);
            System.out.println(" Your Basal Metabolism Rate when you exercise moderately three to five times a week " + moderateExercise);


            double intensely = (BMRw * 1.725);
            System.out.println(" Your Basal Metabolism Rate when you exercise intensely six to seven days a week " + intensely);

            double activeJob = (BMRw * 1.9);
             System.out.println("Your Basal Metabolism Rate when you exercise intensely six to seven days a week while having a physically active job " + activeJob);
     }
```

}
}

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  make a loop by using `while` or `for`

In your case, I suggest you can use `while`

for example

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;
int age;
int x = 1;   
while(x != 0)
{
   System.out.print("Enter name : ");
   name = myScanner.next();

   System.out.print("Enter age  : ");
   age = myScanner.next();

   System.out.print("Do you want to continue?? 1 for yes || 0 for no  : ");
   x = myScanner.next(); //if x = 0 then it will break the loop
}
```

try to run this code!

more information about while loop,
check this out:

https://www.w3schools.com/JAVA/java_while_loop.asp

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I am also new, but what I have learned is that you can put a do...while loop around your code.

```
do
{
   //put all your code you want in the loop here
   //Then, add this:
   System.out.print("Would you like to enter more data? (Y/N)");
   char answer1 = Expo.enterChar(); //The expo class is a separate class that you will 
                                    //need to download/import. You can also look at the
                                    //Expo.html file that I will attach the link for at 
                                    //the end to see if you can do it in a different way.
}
while(answer1 == 'N')
{
   System.out.println("\nThank you for your input.");
   break;
}
```

Now, that might work, but let me know if it doesn't.
Okay, I cannot find the link, but here is the information on the `Expo.enterChar()` that you might need:

enterChar() 
Allows input of a char from the keyboard in a text window. 
Example: 
System.out.print("What is your middle initial? --> "); 
char middleInitial = Expo.enterChar();
Retrieves the first character entered at the keyboard and stores it in the char variable middleInitial.

Comment: I tried the code you sent but it didn't compile so I tried the previous comment and that also didn't compile so I tried to change it up but now I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to have my command to update after each input while in the loop. Here's what i have added https://prnt.sc/r8lxgo

Comment: Okay, well, I see that you have more than one while loop, which might affect it. You say that the program does not compile? What is the compile error message say?